# Verilog: Self bitwise logical operation

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog

I want the `output out` variable to be the output of 4 input AND gates, and the input variable is `input [3:0] in;`

Is there any better option than doing it like this?

`assign out = in[3] & in[2] & in[1] & in[0];`

Is there any other way to do self bitwise operation? What if the vector size of input is large number of bits?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the reduction-AND operator:

```
assign out = &in;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.9 *Reduction operators*.

> The *unary reduction operators* shall perform a bitwise operation on a
> single operand to produce a single-bit result.

This scales to any number of bits in the input signal.